# I can't set a var as the window.screenY

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, although I know Java.

I want an image gallery, which I have down, but the only thing I am able to code opens in a container at the bottom of the page. So what I coded to make it more "professional" was some JavaScript functions to: first of all open it, save the y-position, and scroll all the way down, creating the illusion that it opened the image. After, when you click x, it will scroll up to x=0 and the saved y-position, and it will close the window.

Everything works, but the variable for the y position only saves as 0. Here is the portion of HTML code calling for it:

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="An Image" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">`
```

Here are the JavaScript functions:

```
var windowy;
  function myFunction(imgs) {
    var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
    var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
    expandImg.src = imgs.src;
    imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
    expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
    windowy = window.screenY;
    window.scrollBy(0, 999999999999999);
  }
  function  quitall(imgs) {
    imgs.parentElement.style.display='none';
    window.scrollTo(0,windowy);
  }
```

And finally, here is the html code for closing and scrolling to "windowy":

```
<div class="container">
  <span onclick="quitall(this);" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
  <div id="imgtext"></div>
</div>
```

I am new to this, so if you ask me what "this" or "imgs" are in the function's brackets, I don't know. I just need to know what I'm doing wrong when declaring the variable.

Comment: I know it's not the answer you want right now but it would be much easier to instead use css to position the large image over the top of the page using `.container { position: 0; top: 0; width: 100% } ` then on close set the display property to none?

Comment: I tried it out and it didn't work the way I wanted. I would dig deeper and perfect upon it, but I'm pressed for time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to try `window.pageYOffset` if you want to capture the scroll of the page position.

More info about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset

Comment: Thanks, I just set the windowy as window.pageYOffset and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `window.scrollBy(0, 999999999999999);` is causing your page to scroll to the bottom (999999999999999px in fact) -- you most likely intend to scroll to the top of the newly updated expandImg element. Use `window.scrollTo(0,expandImg.offsetTop);` to scroll the window to the top of offsetTop.

Comment: I intend to store the y-value and then scroll to the bottom where the expanded image is, but if expandImg.offsetTop will send me to the bottom then that helps. Thanks. I just can't seem to store the window.screenY in a variable.